# Date between column_date1 and column_date2 Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I have a table with column `starts_at` and `ends_at` data type datetime.
the input is a date.
How can i select all record where the date (input) that is between `starts_at` and `ends_at` wiht laravel query builder?

Solved :
`Model::where('starts_at', '>=', $date)->where('ends_at', '<=', $date)->get()`

Comment: Show us your attempt please

Comment: _Who on earth UpVoted this question_ Please read what upvotes are for ___HINT: This question show research effort it is useful and clear___ Well it doesn't and it isn't

Comment: I've try `Model::between($date, ['starts_at', 'ends_at'])->get()` but not work

Comment: maybe  whereBetween is usefull for you

Answer (score 1):

If these columns were added to the `$dates` property and you already converted the input date to Carbon instance:

```
if ($model->starts_at->lt($inputDate) && $model->ends_at->gt($inputDate))
```